# Paint Event of a PictureBox is causing flicking- where else can I do this?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am using a SDK from Psion for providing signature control on a mobile device.
I want to draw a rectangle around the signature control (which is a picturebox).
I have put the following into the Paint event, but the problem is that it flickers (as when you sign in the picture box, the picture box is constantly refreshing.

Is there a way I can put this into the load event of the form, so it only loads once?
I know it needs to have the PainEventArgs but I'm not really sure about this.

```
    private void scSignature_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 2f), 0, 0,
            e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1,
            e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1
            );
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What Framework are you using?

Comment: Compact Framework on Windows Mobile 6.5

Comment: Thats what I thought. I was going to suggest DoubleBuffering if it wasn't but the compact framework does not have the Control.SetStyle Method.

Answer (score 7):

Tips to prevent flicker and garbage creation when painting in the CF:

1. Override OnPaintBackground and leave it empty
2. Don't draw directly to the `Graphics` handed to you if you have multiple operations.  Instead create a `Bitmap` buffer, draw into that, and then paint that Bitmap's contents to the `Graphics`
3. Don't create the buffer in #2 above with every Paint.  Create one and reuse it.
4. Don't redraw static items (like a box in a signature control).  Instead, draw it in once to a buffered `Bitmap`, paint that bitmap to the buffer in #2, then paint your dynamic items
5. Don't create Pens, Brushes, etc with every Paint.  Buffer and reuse.

In your case these recommendations might look like this:

```
class Foo : Form
{
    private Bitmap m_background;
    private Bitmap m_backBuffer;
    private Brush m_blackBrush;
    private Pen m_blackPen;

    public Foo()
    {
        m_blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        m_blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

        // redo all of this on Resize as well
        m_backBuffer = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        m_background = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(m_background))
        {
            // draw in a static background here
           g.DrawRectangle(m_blackBrush, ...);
            // etc.
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void  OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(m_backBuffer))
        {
            // use appropriate back color
            // only necessary if the m_background doesn't fill the entire image
            g.Clear(Color.White);

            // draw in the static background
            g.DrawImage(m_background, 0, 0);

            // draw in dynamic items here
            g.DrawLine(m_blackPen, ...);
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_backBuffer, 0, 0);         
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This certainly isn't an elegant approach, but if you can ensure that your picture box has no border at all, you could instead draw a solid rectangle on the picturebox container control. 
Position it right behind the picture box and make it 1px wider on all sides, so it looks like a 1px border around the picture box.

Possible example (overriding the OnPaint method of the control that contains the picturebox):

```
protected override OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPaint(sender, e);
     int x = scSignature.Location.X - 1;
     int y = scSignature.Location.Y - 1;
     int width = scSignature.Size.Width + 2;
     int height = scSignature.Size.Height + 2;
     using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
     {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b,x,y,width,height);
     }

}
```